# Event triggered Variable in AnyLogic

Tags: variables, events, triggers, anylogic

I want to trigger a variable from false to true when my event is done. Is there like an "on Exit" action area for events? There is only "action" and the variable does not change. Or is there a best way to change my variable?

Comment: if your variable doesnt change it means that either your event hasn't happened, or something else changes it back to its original value, or you maybe you are trying to change it to the vaule it already has... impossible to know with info provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *OnExit* code field for *Event*, as these code fields are only used on process modelling blocks (such as Source, Delay, .....). These blocks typically have a flow through them and give the user the opportunity to trigger actions at certain points of time in this flow.

An *Event*, on the other hand, is not part of a process flow. It is a simple trigger, like an egg-timer, to execute a piece of code. This piece of code is executed at the exact time when the event triggers, while the simulation time is paused. So when you want something to happen *after* the code you defined in your Event, just add it at the end of the code.

I attached a screenshot to show you how it could look like to change a variable by an Event:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: thank you very much! I corrected the bug and the variable changes now.